# UTF-8 string - if/else if is not working, but the value equals

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i have an problem with C#, and if/else if string value.

It will return the right value, but it will be checked, and it will ever throw something else(If login is successfull)

Code:

```
public void UserLogin(string Username, string Password)
     {
         ConsoleLog Log = new ConsoleLog();
         WebClient client = new WebClient();
         ServerURL = "http://play.projectzeternity.tk/logonapi.php?login&user=" + Username + "&password=" + Password; // Logon API
         byte[] html = client.DownloadData(ServerURL);
         UTF8Encoding utf = new UTF8Encoding();
         string response = utf.GetString(html); // Here is string - API Response
         string check = Convert.ToString(response); // I tried converting to string, but it's not working.
         Log.Log("Checking response...");
         if (check == "UserNotExist") // User not exist = Successfull login
         {
             Log.Log("Response: UserNotExist");
             ShowError("User doesn't exist!");
         }
         else if (check == "BadArguments") // == Successfull login
         {
             Log.Log("Response: BadArguments");
             ShowError("Invalid arguments!");
         }
         else if (check == "PlayerIsBanned") // == Successfull login
         {
             Log.Log("Response: PlayerIsBanned");
             ShowError("This account is banned for breaking rules!");
         }
         else if (check == "WrongPassword") // = Successfull login
         {
             Log.Log("Response: WrongPassword");
             ShowError("Wrong password!");
         }
         else if (check == "UserAlreadyExist") // = Successfull login
         {
             Log.Log("Response: UserAlreadyExist");
             ShowError("User already exists!");
         }
         else // Successfull login
         {
             Log.Log("Response: " + check);
             IsLoggedIn = true;
             LoginForm.SetActive(false);
             RegisterForm.SetActive(false);
             ConnectionStatus.SetActive(true);
             ConnectionStatusText.text = "Connecting to master...";
             PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings(GameOperations.PZVersion);
             PhotonNetwork.playerName = Name;
             PhotonNetwork.JoinLobby();
         }
         Log.Log("API response: " + response);
         Log.Log("Converted response: " + check);
         Name = Username;
     }
```

It will join into API, and API returns the response, and i will give it into if/else, and value is null, why?

If i will print the response from API (Debug.Log), it will return the right response...

I asked on Unity Awsners, but nobody responsed. :(

Can you help me with that?

Comment: Why do you try to convert string to string?

Comment: What is the value of `response`?

Comment: what "value" is null? There is no "value" in the code you show. Maybe there are trailing whitespaces, upper/lower case issues? When logging out the response, try including it in between quotes and add the output to your question (`Log.Log($"API response: '{response}'")` and `Log.Log($"Converted response: '{check}'")`

Comment: Tried for example.

Value is:
WebClient client = new WebClient();
         ServerURL = "http://play.projectzeternity.tk/logonapi.php?login&user=" + Username + "&password=" + Password; // Logon API
         byte[] html = client.DownloadData(ServerURL);
         UTF8Encoding utf = new UTF8Encoding();
         string response = utf.GetString(html); // Here is string - API Response

Comment: I think you need a `return;` at the end of every if statement, otherwise the last bit of code is executed always.

Comment: Logging is working good, but if/else is returning bad value, for example.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PJQpA7lVm0djppLNrnoOiO7zt-DfDFGD

If i will write if response not equals to defined if/else values, it will throw "Response is not valid"

Comment: @Tudor - Not working, still returning "Response is not valid"

P.S: I repaired API, and it's returning the right responses.

Comment: @Seven9 if/else does not return any value. It just decides what branches of you code to execute. Are you talking about some different code, than you are showing us? The code above can never print anything like "Response is not valid" because thant is not contained. Edit your answer and show us the **actual output** and  the **expected output**. Just mentioning some "values" which can't be seen in your code won't enable us to help you.

Comment: What do you expect Convert.ToString to do, when you supply a string as parameter?

Comment: @derpirscher else
            {
                ShowError("Response is not valid!");
                return;
            }

Comment: And what should we take from that piece of code? Show the actual output your program produces and the output you would expect. Add that to your above question and not scattered in multiple comments, then someone may be able to help you. Right at the moment it's like searching a black cat in a dark room, you don't even sure is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a string directly from a `WebClient` request by using [`WebClient.DownloadString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.110).aspx)—no need to handle raw byte data:

```
 public void UserLogin(string Username, string Password)
 {
     ConsoleLog Log = new ConsoleLog();
     WebClient client = new WebClient();
     ServerURL = "http://play.projectzeternity.tk/logonapi.php?login&user=" + Username + "&password=" + Password; // Logon API
     string check = client.DownloadString(ServerURL);

     // validate the response here...
 }
```

Comment: "Response is not valid"

Comment: And, i'm using Unity 2017.3.0.f3 with Mono, and .NET 4.6 with imported .NET 4.6 libraries.

Comment: Sorry, fixed that. :)